# GridLayout .add error

Tags: java, grid-layout

There seems to be an error in my program that I can't fix for the life of me.

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CalendarGUI extends JPanel {
    ProgramCalendar currentCalendar;
    GregorianCalendar sideCalendar; 
    String[] month = {"January", "February", "March",  "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
            "September", "October", "November", "December"};

    public CalendarGUI(ProgramCalendar pc){
        currentCalendar = pc;
        sideCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        JPanel calendarSidePanel = new JPanel();
        calendarSidePanel.setSize(400,400);
        calendarSidePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //sets month
        JTextPane monthText = new JTextPane();
        monthText.setText(month[sideCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)]);
        calendarSidePanel.add(monthText, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //main part of error
        JPanel sideCalendarMain = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6, 7, 5, 5));

        JTextPane sun = new JTextPane();
        sun.setText("Sun");
        sideCalendarMain.add(sun);

        JTextPane mon = new JTextPane();
        mon.setText("Mon");
        sideCalendarMain.add(mon);

        JTextPane tues = new JTextPane();
        tues.setText("Tues");
        sideCalendarMain.add(tues);

        JTextPane wed = new JTextPane();
        wed.setText("Wed");
        sideCalendarMain.add(wed);

        JTextPane thurs = new JTextPane();
        thurs.setText("Thur");
        sideCalendarMain.add(thurs);

        JTextPane fri = new JTextPane();
        fri.setText("Fri");
        sideCalendarMain.add(fri);

        JTextPane sat = new JTextPane();
        sat.setText("Sat");
        sideCalendarMain.add(sat);

        calendarSidePanel.add(sideCalendarMain, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(calendarSidePanel);
        setSize(1000,1000);
    }

}
```

The problem is that I thought that it would be displayed as such:

```
            April
Sun Mon Tues Wed Thurs Fri Sat
```

rather than

```
 April
Sun Mon
Tues Wed
Thurs Fri
Sat
```

that is currently being displayed.

Am I just misusing GridLayout or is there some other fundamental error that I am missing or is it some random bug. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `GridLayoud`, rows have preference over columns. From the docs:

> When both the number of rows and the number of columns have been set to non-zero values, either by a constructor or by the setRows and setColumns methods, the number of columns specified is ignored. Instead, the number of columns is determined from the specified number of rows and the total number of components in the layout. So, for example, if three rows and two columns have been specified and nine components are added to the layout, they will be displayed as three rows of three columns. Specifying the number of columns affects the layout only when the number of rows is set to zero.

So, you are specifing that your `GridLayout`has 6 rows and thats how the components are beeing layed out. If you wish to specify only one row, change `new GridLayout(6, 7, 5, 5)` to `new GridLayout(1, 7, 5, 5)`.

Comment: The body is going to contain a calendar and so I need a 6x7 grid to host all the days.

Comment: Then, once you have enough components to add, it might work. For now, as the docs say, rows are favored over columns, so your 7 components are beeing layed out to fill 6 rows.

Comment: ahh I see. Thanks. I guess this is the instance where doing testing fails me lol